# C# WPF mouse click event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, click

I'm using C# with WPF. I have a grid of buttons and I need to do the following: If the user presses one button, moves the cursor and releases it on another button, the content of the first button is moved to the other one, something like dragging.

I tried using The previewmousedown and the previewmouseup button events to know which button the mouse is pressed on and which button it is released on but the previewmouseup event is fired also on the button the mouse is pressed on (not on the one the mouse is released on).

Any ideas about how to implement this in other ways, please? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You may want to try `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events!

Comment: Do these buttons need to be clickable _and_ draggable?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do drag & drop is with the built-in `DragDrop` API.  Here's a proof of concept for you, where buttons can be clicked normally ***and*** dragged to swap their content.

If you want to change the behavior so the content is copied or moved (instead of swapped), just change the lines under the comment in `OnButtonDrop`.

**ButtonDragging.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest2.ButtonDragging"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Label x:Name="_statusLabel" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content=" " />
    <Grid x:Name="_grid" />
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**ButtonDragging.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class ButtonDragging
{
    private Button _mouseDownButton;
    private Point _mouseDownLocation;

    public ButtonDragging()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BuildButtonGrid();
    }

    private void BuildButtonGrid()
    {
        const int rows = 5;
        const int columns = 5;

        var starLength = new GridLength(1d, GridUnitType.Star);

        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            _grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = starLength });

        for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = starLength });

        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                var button = new Button { Content = $@"({i}, {j})", AllowDrop = true };

                Grid.SetColumn(button, i);
                Grid.SetRow(button, j);

                button.PreviewMouseMove += OnButtonMouseMove;
                button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnButtonLeftButtonDown;
                button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += OnButtonLeftButtonUp;
                button.Drop += OnButtonDrop;
                button.Click += OnButtonClick;
                button.LostMouseCapture += OnButtonLostMouseCapture;

                _grid.Children.Add(button);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _statusLabel.Content = $@"You clicked {(sender as Button)?.Content}!";
    }

    private void ClearPendingDrag()
    {
        _mouseDownButton = null;
        _mouseDownLocation = default(Point);
    }

    private void OnButtonDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearPendingDrag();

        var source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(object)) as Button;
        if (source == null)
            return;

        var target = (Button)sender;
        if (target == source)
            return;

        var sourceContent = source.Content;
        var targetContent = target.Content;

        // As a proof of concept, this swaps the content of the source and target.
        // Change as necessary to get the behavior you want.

        target.Content = sourceContent;
        source.Content = targetContent;

        _statusLabel.Content = $@"You swapped {sourceContent} with {targetContent}!";
    }

    private void OnButtonLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;

        _mouseDownButton = button;
        _mouseDownLocation = e.GetPosition(button);

        if (!Mouse.Capture(button, CaptureMode.SubTree))
            ClearPendingDrag();
    }

    private void OnButtonLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearPendingDrag();
    }

    private void OnButtonMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDownButton == null)
            return;

        var position = e.GetPosition(_mouseDownButton);
        var distance = position - _mouseDownLocation;

        if (Math.Abs(distance.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(distance.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            var data = new DataObject(typeof(object), button);

            data.SetData("Source", sender);

            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(button, data, DragDropEffects.Move);

            ClearPendingDrag();
        }
    }

    private void OnButtonLostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearPendingDrag();
    }
}
```

Note that there are probably some third-party (and open source) drag and drop solutions out there that are more MVVM-friendly.  It's worth checking out, but this should get you a minimum viable deliverable.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this blog post. This is the best drag and drop article I read online.

From the link below here are the series of events for a drag and drop operation:

1. Dragging is initiated by calling the `DoDragDrop` method for the source control.
   The `DoDragDrop` method takes two parameters:

   `data`, specifying the data to pass

   `allowedEffects`, specifying which operations (copying and/or moving) are allowed 
   A new `DataObject` object is automatically created.
2. This in turn raises the `GiveFeedback` event. In most cases you do not need to worry about the `GiveFeedback` event, but if you wanted to display a custom mouse pointer during the drag, this is where you would add your code.
3. Any control with its `AllowDrop` property set to `True` is a potential drop target. The `AllowDrop` property can be set in the Properties window at design time, or programmatically in the `Form_Load` event.
4. As the mouse passes over each control, the `DragEnter` event for that control is raised. The `GetDataPresent` method is used to make sure that the format of the data is appropriate to the target control, and the Effect property is used to display the appropriate mouse pointer.
5. If the user releases the mouse button over a valid drop target, the `DragDrop` event is raised. Code in the `DragDrop` event handler extracts the data from the `DataObject` object and displays it in the target control.

To detect a mouse Drag operation on the source, source control needs to subscribe to `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseMove`.

```
void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         this.DragSource.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
         this.DragSource.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(DragSource_PreviewMouseMove);
     }
```

To prevent from starting a false drag & drop operation where the user accidentally drags, you can use `SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance`  and `SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance`.

```
void DragSource_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && !IsDragging)
            {
                Point position = e.GetPosition(null);

                if (Math.Abs(position.X - _startPoint.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||

                    Math.Abs(position.Y - _startPoint.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)

                {
                  StartDrag(e); 
                }
            }
        }

        void DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        }
```

Now you detect a drag operation, all you need to know is dropping into.

A simple scenario without any effect could be done like this.

```
private void StartDrag(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            IsDragging = true;

            DataObject data = new DataObject(System.Windows.DataFormats.Text.ToString(), "abcd");

            DragDropEffects de = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this.DragSource, data, DragDropEffects.Move);

            IsDragging = false;
        }
```

I think this can get you started. I really recommend to read the complete post from the link.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2007/07/12/drag-amp-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end/